# what are the numbers in tensorboard and how do I name them on pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I'm seeing all these numbers on tensorboard when using pytorch. Some variables are named properly but intermediate computations seem to be labeled with numbers. Is there a way to name them? If I remember correctly, tensorflow tensors take namespace arguments. Is there an equivalent argument in pytorch?

[image]